# Scenario: There is this web page which has a list of 10 web link. Click on each web link and open in new window or tab using selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I got this as an interview question. 
Need help to solve this
Scenario: There is this web page which has a list of 10 web link. Click on each web link and open in new window or tab using selenium Java .
Example [here](https://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html).

Click on all **tutorial** from **WebDriver** Tutorial. which should open in a new tab

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this using the `JavascriptExecutor`

1. First, Capture all the required link element in list
2. Iterate all the list element and get the href value from the anchor tag
3. Open the window using the JavaScript executor by passing the above href value

**Code:**

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Selenium Tutorial"));

    List<WebElement> tutorialLinkList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//strong[contains(text(),'Tutorial')]/ancestor::a"));

    JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;

    //I have just clicked only 10 link. If you want to iterate all the available links, then use foreach loop
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        String url=tutorialLinkList.get(i).getAttribute("href");
        js.executeScript("window.open(arguments[0])",url); //New Tab will be opened
    }
}
```

**Note:** Here, I have opened only the first 10 links in different tab. If you wish to open  all the link in new tab,then I would suggest to use `foreach` loop as below

```
    for(WebElement tutoialLink : tutorialLinkList){

        String url=tutoialLink.getAttribute("href");
        js.executeScript("window.open(arguments[0])",url); //New Tab will be opened
    }
```

**Edit:** **Code with Actions Class**

It looks right click is not working in that URL and hence, you can open the link is new tab by performing `Ctr + click` action as below

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Selenium Tutorial"));

    List<WebElement> tutorialLinkList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//strong[contains(text(),'Tutorial')]/ancestor::a"));

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    //I have just clicked only 10 link. If you want to iterate all the available links, then use foreach loop
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

        action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(tutorialLinkList.get(i)).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
    }
}
```

Comment: @cruisepandey: No. tutorialLinkList will hold all the required link elements.so, we can just iterate all the list and extract the href value. I have tested with the above code and all the links are getting opened in new tab

Comment: @cruisepandey thanks for help but can I do without js.executeScript.

Comment: @AmishaDamani: Yeah we can achieve using actions class .Please check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

As per your response in comment section, you can achieve the same behavior through **Actions class** which is available in **selenium**.

You can try out this **code** :

```
public class Amisha  {

    static WebDriver driver ; 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\user***\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html");
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,650)", "");
        List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//strong[text()='WebDriver Tutorial']/following-sibling::table[1]/descendant::a"));
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        for(WebElement ele:element) {
            action.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).moveToElement(ele).click().keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).build().perform();
        }

    }
}
```